# R dataframe using lead with criteria

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this :

| Name | Date | Drink |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Josh | 2022-06-24 | Welcome Drink |
| Josh | 2022-07-01 | Beer |
| Josh | 2022-07-03 | Wine |
| Josh | 2022-07-24 | Cocktail |
| Josh | 2022-07-28 | Wine |
| Josh | 2022-07-29 | Beer |

How to easily get the first time Josh had each drink after he had 1st welcome drink ?

Desired output :

| Name | Welcome drink | 1stCocktail | 1stWine | 1stBeer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Josh | 2022-06-24 | 2022-07-24 | 2022-07-03 | 2022-07-01 |

I would like to use lead but I can only get it to work if I work on separate dataframes with only one kind of drink at a time, but how could I get the next row for each kind of drink

Comment: Greetings! Generally speaking, it is always better to provide a minimal reproducible dataset for us to work with on SO. One way of achieving this is by using the `dput` command. You can find out how to use this function by watching this video:
https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:
First we make the make sure that the date is actually a date, then we group the dataframe by Name and Drink. In this example, grouping by name is not really necessary, but I imagine that in a longer dataset there would be more names. Then we select only the first occurrence of each drink using `filter`. Lastly we pivot wider to get the desired output that you specified. I did not change the column names to your desired output because it is usually not a good idea to start a variable with a number.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my.dat <- tribble(~Name, ~Date, ~Drink,
                  "Josh" , "2022-06-24" , "Welcome Drink",
                  "Josh" ,"2022-07-01" ,"Beer",
                  "Josh" ,"2022-07-03" ,"Wine",
                  "Josh" ,"2022-07-24" ,"Cocktail",
                  "Josh" ,"2022-07-28" ,"Wine",
                  "Josh" ,"2022-07-29" ,"Beer")

my.dat |>
  mutate(Date = lubridate::ymd(Date)) |>
  group_by(Name, Drink) |>
  filter(Date == first(Date)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Drink, values_from = Date)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#> # Groups:   Name [1]
#>   Name  `Welcome Drink` Beer       Wine       Cocktail  
#>   <chr> <date>          <date>     <date>     <date>    
#> 1 Josh  2022-06-24      2022-07-01 2022-07-03 2022-07-24
```